# Flash not working in Midori

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash

I have been using Midori for a while now, and got tired of flash not working so tried to install it.

I checked the checkbox "Install flash and other 3rd party proprietary stuff" button when I installed my distro, so have flashplugin-installer installed. I am using Elementary OS 0.2 Beta 2, based on ubuntu 12.04 with the 3.5 kernel from 12.10.

These are the things I have tried yet:

- Re-installed flashplugin-installer via both apt-get and software centre
- Downloaded the .tar.gz flash directory from adobe, and put libflashplayer.so in both /lib/mozilla/plugins and in /home/user/.config/mozilla/plugins.
- added 'export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins"' to my .bashrc
- added the line "enable-plugins=true" to the midori config
- On the midori faq they tell you to "nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i", which returns "ERROR: libssl3.so: cannot open sharet object file: no such file or directory". Have searched for this error and not found a fix

I have followed the steps on these threads

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=917636
2. http://puppylinux.info/topic/midori-browser-Flash not working in Midoriwhere-to-install-flashplayer
3. http://midoribrowser.org/faqs/

Comment: Only so you guys know, i still watch this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this simple trick and it worked for me. Check the path in your system accordingly

64-bit system

cp /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib64/midori/.

32-bit system

cp /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/midori/.

Close Midori(if open) and open it again..flash player will work..

Answer (score 1):

I had so many troubles with flash in firefox & Midori. Finally, I found this bash script that fixed **EVERYTHING :)** It was also very user friendly.

1. Download this small bash script: [freshplayer_maintainer.sh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg93xafk9h12ioq/freshplayer_maintainer.sh?dl=0)
2. `Ctrl + Alt + t` to open the terminal
3. Go to the save location `cd /where/I/saved/the/file/`
4. Run bash on the file `bash freshplayer_maintainer.sh`
5. Once running, select option 1, to install freshplayerplugin.
6. When prompted, choose to install system wide. DONE!